# Running multiple programs in a single cmd instance

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run multiple instances of a program at the same time while also having their outputs be echoed into the same cmd instance. The issue is I can only get one out of the two aforementioned clauses to work properly.

What I need to know is an efficient way to simultaneously run multiple programs at the same time and have them be in the same window.

```
color 08
echo | start [application] (args)
timeout /t 1
echo | start [application] (args)
timeout /t 1
echo | start [application] (args)
timeout /t 1
echo | start [application] (args)
```

This method is what I currently have. I thought this would work because the would have it run multiple instances at the same time, while the echo kept it in the same window. What actually happened is that the applications run in multiple windows for no reason I have knowledge of.

Comment: Why would `echo` do anything to keep the command in the same window? Take a look at `start /?`, specifically the `/b` flag.

Comment: @SomethingDarkUsing `start /b` managed to make the program work near-perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please do not add solutions to the question area. We have an answer area for such things.

Comment: @compo Thanks for letting me know, I reposted the comment answer in the answer area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered in the comment section.

To make this work, use `start /b [application] (args)` for all the applications you need to run. This however does have a chance for command prompt to overwrite a line if two outputs happen around the same time. For the program I showed before, use this:

```
color 08
start /b [application] (args)
timeout /t 1
start /b [application] (args)
timeout /t 1
start /b [application] (args)
timeout /t 1
start /b [application] (args)
```